# Making a button fill the entire width of a div on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following code here: https://codepen.io/gg-the-solid/pen/KKrrGwQ?editors=1100

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="text-caption">
      <b>Title Text</b>
      <div class="or-get-started">
         Caption text
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="button-right">
      <a href="https://www.google.com" rel="noopener"> <button class="cta-button">Lorem ipsum dolor →</button></a>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is that when it collapses into one single column, I want the button to fill the entire width of the div.

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .outer {
    flex-direction: column;
    }
  .cta-button {
    width:100%;
  }
```

I've tried using width:100%; at the bottom of the css but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it's container width to 100% as well and then it will work. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/rakibul2010islam/pen/yLQQRMx?editors=1100)

```
.button-right{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.outer,
.or-get-started {
  position: relative;
}
.or-get-started {
  align-self: stretch;
  font-size: var(--font-size-base);
  color: var(--med-grey);
}
.text-caption {
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 8px;
}
.create-a-free {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.cta-button,
.outer {
  border-radius: var(--br-5xs);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.cta-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #224949;
  padding: 16px var(--padding-5xl);
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: var(--font-size-base);
  color: var(--extra-light-grey);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  border: 1px solid var(--extra-light-grey);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: var(--padding-5xl);
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: var(--neutral-text);
  font-family: var(--font-inter);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

:root {

  /* font sizes */
  --font-size-base: 16px;

  /* Colors */
  --extra-light-grey: #f3f2f2;
  --med-grey: #828282;
  --neutral-text: #090924;

  /* Paddings */
  --padding-5xl: 24px;

  /* border radiuses */
  --br-5xs: 8px;

  /* Effects */
  --shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .outer {
    flex-direction: column;
    }
  .button-right{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cta-button {
    width:100%;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="text-caption">
    <b>Title Text</b>
    <div class="or-get-started">
      Caption text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-right">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" rel="noopener"> <button class="cta-button">Lorem ipsum dolor →</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```